# Plotly / Dash: Multiple filters

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to implement a few data filters to preselect the data by certain criteria. These filters should be diagrams itself, i.e. a pie chart (e.g. where one can select a continent) and a time line (e.g. where one can select a time-span). Most importantly, I need to **apply multiple filters from mutliple diagrams without them resetting every time I filter by selecting another diagram**.

However, I do not know how to implement this. I found something old using dash.dependencies.Events, but that is not supported anymore.

Whenever I filter by a criterion in diagram A and then want to filter by another criterion from diagram B, diagram A gets reset.

Since this is probably a situation encountered by many people, and since dash does not seem to support this natively, I wanted to ask whether anyone has a workaround on this?

**//edit:** Here is a simple example. I can filter by clicking on a datapoint on the bar graph above. But **whenever I click on a point on the line graph below, it resets the settings from the bar graph. I want to keep both.**

```
import datetime

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='graph')
    ])

# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph', 'selectedData')])
def update_graph_live(input):
    print(input)
    data = {
        'x': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'y': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'a': [0,-1,-2],
        'b': [100,101,102]
    }

    # Create the graph with subplots
    fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
    fig['layout']['margin'] = {
        'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
    }
    fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}
    fig['layout']['clickmode'] = 'event+select'

    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['x'],
        'y': data['y'],
        'name': 'xy',
        'type': 'bar',
    }, 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace({
        'x': data['a'],
        'y': data['b'],
        'name': 'ab',
        'mode': 'lines+markers',
        'type': 'scatter'
    }, 2, 1)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please provide code examples of what you tried and errors you received, HOW rae you trying to filter by criterion?

Comment: Here we go. Now, do you have an idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I managed to find a workaround.

First of all, as @russellr mentioned, `dash.dependencies.State` can be passed, but it will not trigger a callback. I would like callbacks to be triggered on multiple filters without them resetting each other.

Now, for the good people at Dash, disabling this reset would enable endless loops, so it there is a lot of sense in disabling it.

The way I did it is that I introduced `Dropdown` lists for filtering, and callbacks only go from the `value` of the Dropdown to the `figure` of the graph.

I select multiple conditions on the dropdowns, get the (non-interactive) visualisations from it. It might be not as pretty, but the app still got good useability feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it seems your problem is that selecting data in any of the graphs in the figure of the `graph` component, i.e. **the output of your function**, triggers the Input(`graph`,'selectedData') to that same function!

So what you need to do is separate the graphs into separate dcc.Graph things and use `dash.dependencies.State` to listen to and maintain each graph's `selectedData` property.